# Variable should not return to default value

Tags: php, variables

```
<?php

$transVar = "000000001";
$transF = (1+ $transVar);

echo "<br>";
echo $transF;

?>
```

I need the output of the code to be 0000000002 and be incrementing on refresh even closing and reloading the script, I don't seem to be getting it, Any help?

Comment: Use a session variable to make a variable persist between calls to the script.

Comment: When you run a computer program it's always like it never ran before - variables held in memory do not keep their values between each separate run. If you want values to be kept ("persisted" in more technical language) between each run then you have to specifically write code to save and then retrieve those values. You can write to a file on disk or to a database, for example. In a web application you can use the Session in certain circumstances - that might suit you in this case, potentially. It stores data temporarily for the duration of the user's session and is only accessible to that user

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
  if (isset($_SESSION["TransVar"])) {
    $_SESSION["TransVar"] += 1;
  } else {
    $_SESSION["TransVar"] = 1;
  }

  echo str_pad($_SESSION["TransVar"], 8, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

When the page loads the first time we set the session value to 1, then increment it after each page refresh. We keep the session value as a number, and pad it with zeroes instead of saving the value as a string.

Keep in mind that this value is only persisted as long as the session is alive, so it won't be stored forever. If you need to persist this value indefinetely, then you need a different approach.

Read more about PHP sessions: https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php